# React change route/page/container background color

Tags: css, reactjs, background

I would like to change the page background color when moving from /Login to / or 'Home page'.

I tried like this, but the '/Login' page css keeps overwriting the '/' pages css rule.

Login.js

```
import './Login.css';
```

Login.css

```
body {
    background: #2DC04D;
    /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #00C7E7, #2DC04D);
    /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #00C7E7, #2DC04D);
    /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}
```

And in:

Home.js

```
import './Home.css';
```

Home.css

```
body {
    background: white;
}
```

What would be the correct way to change certain pages/routes/containers background color?

Comment: Instead of body try giving the outermost div of both login and home page a class and apply css on them

Comment: Then I would have to force a height to the Div and that would make other things not work so well :/

Comment: If you'd like to mount and unmount CSS as you mount/unmount components, look into this technique: https://medium.com/@jviereck/modularise-css-the-react-way-1e817b317b04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Antd - is there anyway to change background color of the Card title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44511421/antd-is-there-anyway-to-change-background-color-of-the-card-title)