# Antd - is there anyway to change background color of the Card title?

Tags: reactjs, antd

By adding the style attribute I can only change the color of the body part of the Card component. How can I change the title part as well?

```
<Card title='Card title' bordered loading={this.onLoading()}
    style={{ backgroundColor: '#aaaaaa' }}>
    <Row type='flex' justify='center'>
    <h1>Card content</h1>
    </Row>
</Card>
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

The following worked for me. I had to remove the background color of the entire card and set a different background color both for the Head and Body content:

```
<Card
title="Track title"
style={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)', border: 0 }}
headStyle={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)', border: 0 }}
bodyStyle={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4)', border: 0 }}
>
    <Card.Meta
    description="Track author"
    />
</Card>
```

Result:

[image: Result after applying 3 styles]

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is for latest version of ant design..
Question is for old version where card doesn't have headStyle attribute

Answer (score 5):

For antd version 4.x

You can use `headStyle` and `bodyStyle` property to change the background color

```js
 <Card
    title="Card title"
    headStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#5c6cfa', color: '#ffffff' }}
    bodyStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#a9bbff' }}
    bordered={false}
    style={{ width: 300 }}
  >
    <p>Card content</p>
    <p>Card content</p>
    <p>Card content</p>
  </Card>
```

OR

You can customize the css class

```css
.ant-card-head {
  background: #5c6cfa;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.ant-card-body {
  background: #a9bbff;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Finally i have no choice and use css to get around that. The structure of the antd card is like

```
<div class="ant-card ant-card-bordered">
    <div class="ant-card-head" \>
    <div class="ant-card-body" \>
```

and .ant-card-head has the background style as #fff.

if I do sth like `<Card style={{background:"#aaa"}}`, it will override the .ant-card class. If I do `<Card bodyStyle={{background:"#aaa"}}`, it will override the .ant-card-body class and I couldn't find any direct way to override the .ant-card-head class, so I ended up use css to set the .ant-card-body background to none and it works.

Comment: Use `headStyle`!

Answer (score 2):

You have some typo. `style:{{backgroundColor:'#aaaaaa'}}` should be `style={{ backgroundColor: '#aaaaaa' }}` and it works for me:

[image]

---

Using the same code and it does work:

[image]

[image]

I may need to inspect your page to know why it doesn't work for you

Comment: Thanks for quick response. It still doesn't work for me. I edited the post and added an example.

Comment: Exact same code, it does work for me.. Can you inspect the style of title?

Comment: BTW, are u using 'antd' for producing the result, i.e., `import {Card} from 'antd'`

Comment: Yes. I simply use `import { Card, Row } from 'antd'`

Comment: with `"antd": "^2.11.0"`